How to deploy Laravel Reverb in production with Cyberpanel?
I can't get Laravel Reverb to work for me on my server with cyberpanel.
I have configured everything well, when I test my application from local pointing without SSL(WS) I can connect and so far so good, but when I uploaded it to keep it in production is where I find the problem:
WebSocket connection to'wss://domain.com/app/sdfsdsdf323?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed:

I have tried many things from setting up reverse proxy and I get nothing, I can't get it to work.
Has anyone here configured Laravel Reverb in Cyberpanel?
Here are my configurations.
Laravel .env
REVERB_APP_ID=123456
REVERB_APP_KEY=sdfsdsdf323
REVERB_APP_SECRET=sdfsdsdf323
REVERB_SERVER_HOST="127.0.0.1"
REVERB_SERVER_PORT=8080
REVERB_HOST="domain.com"
REVERB_PORT=443
REVERB_SCHEME=http
REVERB_LOCAL_CERT="/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem"
#REVERB_LOCAL_PK="/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem"

React .env
REACT_APP_REVERB_APP_KEY=sdfsdsdf323
REACT_APP_REVERB_HOST=domain.com
REACT_APP_REVERB_PORT=443
REACT_APP_REVERB_SCHEME=https
REACT_APP_REVERB_PATH="/ws"

Laravel Echo configuration
window.Pusher = Pusher;
    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'reverb',
        key: process.env.REACT_APP_REVERB_APP_KEY,
        wsHost: process.env.REACT_APP_REVERB_HOST,
        wsPort: process.env.REACT_APP_REVERB_PORT ?? 8080,
        wssPort: process.env.REACT_APP_REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
        
//wsPath: process.env.REACT_APP_REVERB_PATH ?? "/",
        forceTLS: (process.env.REACT_APP_REVERB_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
        enabledTransports: ['ws','wss'],
        authorizer: (channel, options) => {
            return {
                authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
                    axios.post('/api/broadcasting/auth', {
                        socket_id: socketId,
                        channel_name: channel.name
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        callback(null, response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        callback(error);
                    });
                }
            };
        },
    });

The application works fine when it is local. I have the websocket server on a VPS with cyberpanel and then run the React app locally, The application works fine when it is local as I mentioned, but when I deploy it to production on a hosting is when it gives the problem that does not connect, I read that it is a certificate issue but try to configure it and then I got no luck.
Some other discussions I was consulting but I tried to do everything they said and got no luck at all.
https://github.com/laravel/reverb/issues/107
https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/50675

May I know if you are using OLS or LSWS?  In OpenLiteSpeed, it supports websocket ws:// only.

@Eric Yes, I am using OpenLiteSpeed. Any way to make it support wss since the browser does not support ws connections in production.

ws:// is for the backend, you can still let OLS handle the SSL request in the frontend. See https://github.com/laravel/reverb/issues/107 for other similar cases, and https://docs.openlitespeed.org/config/reverseproxy/websocket/ to set OLS as a websocket proxy.
